# Still having blue smoke

Tags: nissan, exhaust, smoke

I have no idea in car engines. My car is having a blue smoke in the exhaust. The car mechanic suggest to change the piston rings and valve seals. After he replaced it I still get this blue smoke when climbing on flyover roads, and the smoke does not smell good. Please help. Thanks

Btw my car is nissan lec 1997

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Is there blue smoke on startup? Also, what was done to break in the engine? Was the cylinders honed at the time it was re-ringed? What *exactly* was done to the engine? Just the rings, or was there any machining done to the block?

Comment: On startup there is no smoke. The smoke appears when I was climbing on flyover roads and pressing the gas hard. Just the rings and valve seal was replaced.

Comment: It sounds as though the oil rings haven't seated correctly. This is *usually* caused during a re-ring when the mechanic doesn't "bust the glaze" on the cylinder. Without the proper hone in the cylinders, not only will the oil rings not seal, neither will the compression rings, which can cause a loss of compression and power. One question I didn't ask was, is this a gas or diesel engine? All-in-all, it sounds as though the mechanic still has some work to perform.

Comment: Its a Gas engine. I kinda feel loss of power tho. The blue smoke is getting worse 

Comment: Take it back to the mechanic and tell them to make it right.